# Distance transform - the function does not work properly

Tags: python, opencv, distance

I am trying to get the distance transform image, but I am getting a bad result.

Image:

[image]

Code:

```
import cv2
import imutils
import numpy as np

photo = 'dog.jpg'

img = cv2.imread(photo)
ybprc = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCrCb)
inrangeHsv = cv2.inRange(ybprc, np.array([0, 135, 85]), np.array([255, 180, 135]))
retval, otsu = cv2.threshold(inrangeHsv, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cnts = cv2.findContours(otsu.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
mask = cv2.drawContours(otsu, [c], -1, (0,255,0), 2)
out = cv2.distanceTransform(mask, distanceType=cv2.DIST_L2, maskSize=5)

cv2.imshow("distance_transform", out)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And result is:
[image]

But the result should be more like:

[image]

How should I fix it?

Comment: can you share the sample code that generated the "horse distance transform"?

Comment: @teng It's just a downloaded image from the google, sorry. But I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61211151/drawing-inscribing-circle-into-thresholded-image)

Comment: I believe that the distance transform works on a binary image and not contours. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga8a0b7fdfcb7a13dde018988ba3a43042

Comment: @fmw42 Hmm... I have tried `out = cv2.distanceTransform(otsu, distanceType=cv2.DIST_L2, maskSize=5)` but result is the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is that imshow() will not present the image properly. You need to do imwrite().

This works for me in Python/OpenCV.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read input
img = cv2.imread('dog.jpg')

# convert to YCbCr
ycrcb = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCrCb)

# use inRange thresholding
thresh = cv2.inRange(ycrcb, np.array([0, 135, 85]), np.array([255, 180, 135]))

# get outer contour
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
big_contour = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)

# draw filled contour on black background
filled = np.zeros_like(thresh)
cv2.drawContours(filled, [big_contour], -1, (255), cv2.FILLED)

# get distance transform
result = filled.copy()
result = cv2.distanceTransform(result, distanceType=cv2.DIST_L2, maskSize=3, dstType=cv2.CV_8U)

# stretch to full dynamic range
result2 = cv2.normalize(result, None, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)

# save result
cv2.imwrite('dog_thresh.png', thresh)
cv2.imwrite('dog_filled_contour.png', filled)
cv2.imwrite('dog_distance.png', result)
cv2.imwrite('dog_distance_normalized.png', result2)

# show results
# note result image will look binary
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("filled", filled)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Threshold image:

[image]

Filled contour:

[image]

Distance Result:

[image]

Normalized Distance Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've got same problem with You and there is a useful solution in documentation
You must use normalize

```
dist_transform=cv2.distanceTransform(opening,cv2.DIST_L2,3)
cv2.normalize(dist_transform, dist_transform, 0, 1.0,cv2.NORM_MINMAX) 
cv2.imshow(dist_transform)
cv2.waitkey()
```

[you can find here the documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/dbd/tutorial_distance_transform.html)